# flashing update from recovery

Tags: recovery-mode

I have cwm recovery installed (not the official version) and I backed up my current stock Rom through it. It backed up bootloader, system etc... And reported some backups have failed . Which are backups necessary to retain current stock Rom if I flash another custom Rom?

Comment: /data, /system/ should be enough, /cache and /dalvik cache if you want to be on the safe side. What backups have failed?

Comment: I don't know exactly. But following files have 0 bytes in backup directory data.ext4.tar, cache.ext4.tar, system.ext4.tar

Comment: The important ones are /boot (this is the kernel and is very critical), /system -> this contains the rest of the Android OS,  /data -> this contains user data such as apps, their settings, wifi and some misc stuff. This gets cleared when you do a factory reset, so it is optional but convenient to have as a backup. /recovery -> often not flashed by a ROM. The first two must be backed up to retain a ROM.